# Addressing Incremental Refresh for APIs Error in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, incremental

I am trying to access a weather API from the Power B.I platform and want to incorporate the incremental refresh. I get an error, even after I have tried to add the `StartRange` and `EndRange` in the parameters section.

The API only contains a station id as the parameter.
For example: `API/weather.com/{station-id}`
Example:

> Api/weather.com/1
> Api/weather.com/2

When I call the API, it is pulling this data:

These are the steps I applied to clean the data:

[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwOjP.png)

This is what it looks like after I have split some of the text, and cleaned it up, so the date/data can be readable.

[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg7nO.png)

I have followed some YouTube videos/the power B.I guide that tells me to follow these steps of creating parameters and clicking filter in the date/time column.
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

But I still receive the same error even after adding the parameters. Is it because the API data is broken and it does not detect the date parameter? Is it because my API needs a date parameter in the API link?

What are your thoughts/steps I should take to fix this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not how incremental refresh works. The data source needs to have all the data, then with incremental refresh, PBI will only import the between the dates.

In your case, you don't have a data source (or API) that accepts a date range. It seems like the API you are using will only give the current day's data. You are going to have to persist these daily readings in your own data source, then have PBI import from there. For example, you could use Power Automate (flow) that runs daily, calls the API, and adds the data to a new row in Excel. Then from PBI, load from there.

Comment: I've been contemplating using the Power Automate platform with a timer trigger to load the API data, which is subsequently transferred into an Excel file. Following this, my Power BI utilizes incremental refresh to update the data from the Excel file. However, I'm curious about the cost implications. Is this approach considered expensive or cost-effective to run? I understand that the expenses depend on the frequency of execution, but is there an average cost associated with this process?